# String returning with a null reference value

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a silly error I can't get shot of.

I'm using a string to check the name of folders and their extension types. I'm doing this so I can navigate between folders. This works fine with my first folder selection, however, when I try and click on a second one I get null reference exception.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
 string clickObject = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
 int index = clickObject .LastIndexOf('.');
 string extension = clickObject .Substring(index + 1, clickObject .Length - index - 1);
  if (extension == "folder")
  {
      // do stuff
   }
```

After this I simply check the files in my folder.

When I go back to the root of my searchable folder and click on another directory, that is when i get the error and the line `string clickObject = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` is highlighted.

At the end of my method where I set this I tried setting `clickedObject = null;` I tried to remove the string that was contained with `clickObject.Remove(0);` but the error still persists.

How can I clear the information held in clickedObject so I can overwrite it with new information?

Edit

Sorry forgot to mention when I go back to the root I have a button that calls this method:

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            result = client.DownloadString("http://foo.foo.com/images/getDirectoryList.php");
        }

        string[] names = result.Split('|');
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(name);
        }
        listBox1.Update();

        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

However, when I click an item in the list box, its the first set of code that gets used and that is in a sepearate method.

Comment: It is likely that `SelectedItem` evaluates to null then: `(null).ToString()` will definitely not work.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? You shouldn't have to "clear" `clickedObject`. Selecting a new item in the list will overwrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event you need to cope with it being null as there are cases where it won't be set.

Therefore in your handler you must check that `listBox1.SelectedItem` is not null before trying to convert it to a string:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a bug.. but I too have come across this before.

The problem is, that `SelectedItem` isn't always available during the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.. or sometimes not at all.

The fix is to access the item directly:

```
string clickObject = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Also, while you're there.. you can use `File.GetExtension` method in `System.IO` to get the extension (instead of doing it yourself):

```
using System.IO;

string extension = File.GetExtension(clickObject);
```